# super key not working in Neovim on Linux

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, linux

I'm trying to create a shortcut, but I can't get vim to recognize my `super` key. I tried the following combinations:

```
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<A-h>"] = ":BufferLineCyclePrev<cr>"
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<A-l>"] = ":BufferLineCycleNext<cr>"

lvim.keys.normal_mode["<M-h>"] = ":BufferLineCyclePrev<cr>"
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<M-l>"] = ":BufferLineCycleNext<cr>"

lvim.keys.normal_mode["<D-h>"] = ":BufferLineCyclePrev<cr>"
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<D-l>"] = ":BufferLineCycleNext<cr>"
```

The above shortcuts work for `Alt+h|l` but not for `Super+h|l`.

I tried with running `Neovim` in the terminal (`alacritty`) and also with a graphical client (`Neovide`)... without luck.

I use `arch` linux + `xorg`.

I have no problems with the `super` key in other apps.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do about this?

Comment: I don't know about the graphical clients, but most (as far as I know, all actually) terminals don't really recognize the Windows/"Super" key. It's just not something that's in the terminal text protocol. Although there are ways to work around this by configuring your WM to make Win+key send some specific key code you can pick up in Neovim, but it's a bit ugly and will only work on your system with that specifically configured WM.

Comment: For neovide, I found this: https://github.com/neovide/neovide/wiki/Configuration#use-logo-key

Comment: @MartinTournoij This was very helpful and you are right, alacritty could not recognize `super`. I didn't try `neovide_input_use_logo` for neovide, because a found a hack for alacritty, but this setting looks like a valid solution as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Tournoij was right, alacritty could not recognize the `super` key.

I ended up using this hacky solution.

With these key bindings in `alacritty.yaml`:

```
key_bindings:

 - { key: H,         mods: Super,       chars: "\x1bh"                       }
 - { key: L,         mods: Super,       chars: "\x1bl"                       }
```

I could make the `Super` key act like the `Alt` key for `h` and `l`, allowing me to use: `<A-h>` `<A-l>` in nvim.

More info on this hack: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/62#issuecomment-347552058